# Old URLs after moving a Magento install to new domain

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm wanting to move a Magento site from an old domain (olddomain.com) to a new domain (newdomain.com).

How do I make sure that after moving domains, people visiting any page of the old domain (eg. olddomain.com/products/three-legged-table) get redirected to the same page on the new domain (newdomain.com/products/three-legged-table)?

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess will be the best place to do so. You can write below code to redirect all old domain URL to new domain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Hope it helps.